# Run project in root folder and not "staging"

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt

I'm developing my first application with [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.com/) Using version `2.2.0`

Browsing tutorials I see that the `run`command is to be used in development, but I see a small complication.

I have my project in `/home/user/project`

But whenever I hit `run` it deploys from `/home/user/.sbt/0.13/staging/86fad3d4ade1b670f10a/project`

So when I make an alteration on my root folder, it doesn't change anything in the running application. So what should I do to make it run from the actual project folder, so that I can see alterations on the fly?

Right now I need to do this to update my running project:

```
Ctrl + C
sudo rm -rf ~/.sbt/0.13/staging/86fad3d4ade1b670f10a
play
run
```

And that'll make it update again, but when I do that, the `staging` is recreated

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem, it creates the `staging` directory because I don't have root privileges in the project folder. If I run `play` with root privileges, it works as expected.